# Poor normal map result when the model is lit by a strong light

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normal-map, shadows

I have modeled a detail piece for a project I'm working on. I've used the multi resolution modifier to sculp it, and then I baked a normal map from a higher subdiv level to a lower one. Standard stuff.

[image]

The normal map looks fine in general, but under some light conditions it breaks a bit in some spots.

[image]

I think that's the underlying geometry that's messing up stuff a bit... I know that normal maps have limits and that there's quite a difference in polycount, but I was hoping it wouldn't be so drastic. Especially since under different light conditions it doesn't show up (or it's less noticeable I guess).
I was wondering if I messed up something or if this is just how it is.

[image]

This is the map, resized to 1024x1024 for size, but the original is 4kx4k (I know there are two error spots on it, but it's fine in this case because it's on the back of the model and they're never gonna be seen). Face normals on the model are all pointing outwards (just in case you're wondering).

Node setup:

[image]

Comment: Silly question, but I just have to ask... You did remember to set the normal map to non-color data, right?

Comment: Yes I did that, also did it while baking the map. I forgot to add the node setup, I'll do it now.